# Open dialer with phone number when phone number tapped on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to show the dialer on mobile when a user taps a phone number on my website. I want to show the number they tapped on the dialer screen. Is this possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To make a link open the dialer with the number you specify, use `tel:xxxxxxxxxx` as the `href` of the link, where the x's represent your phone number. For example:

```html
<a href="tel:1234567890">(123) 456-7890</a>
```

An excellent article on telephone links can be found here: [The Current State of Telephone Links](https://css-tricks.com/the-current-state-of-telephone-links/).